# How to create ".nomedia" file and store images inside it Programmatically?

Tags: java, android, android-gallery

For my Application images are stored in my phone's internal storage and images are visible in the gallery, but my client wants images will not be visible inside the gallery.

I added .nomedia file manually inside the folder where images are stored and it disappears but I took new image again it is visible in the gallery.

So how can I do it programmatically so that images will not appear in my gallery?

**Here is my code.**

```
public  void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode,data);

if(resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK){

    if(requestCode==REQUEST_CAMERA){
        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
        if (null != selectedImageUri) {
            // Get the path from the Uri

            String path = getPathFromURI(selectedImageUri);
            File file = new File(path);
            Bitmap  bmp = CommonMethod.compressImage(file, getContext());
            Log.e(TAG, "onActivityResult --: "+ String.format("Size : %s", getReadableFileSize(file.length())));

            mCustomerImage =  CommonMethod.bitmapToByteArray(bmp);
            imageTemplateStr = Base64.encodeToString(mCustomerImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
            Log.e(TAG, "image: "+ imageTemplateStr );
            imageCustomer.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        }

    }else if(requestCode==SELECT_FILE){
        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
        if (null != selectedImageUri) {
            // Get the path from the Uri

            String path = getPathFromURI(selectedImageUri);
            File file = new File(path);
            Bitmap  bmp = CommonMethod.compressImage(file, getContext());
            Log.e(TAG, "onActivityResult --: "+ String.format("Size : %s", getReadableFileSize(file.length())));

            mCustomerImage =  CommonMethod.bitmapToByteArray(bmp);
            imageTemplateStr = Base64.encodeToString(mCustomerImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
            Log.e(TAG, "image: "+ imageTemplateStr );

            imageCustomer.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        }

}
```

**getPathFromUri method**

```
public String getPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    String res = null;
    String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        res = cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
    cursor.close();
    return res;
}
```

**compressImage() method .**

```
public static Bitmap compressImage(File imgFile, Context context) {
    Bitmap compressedImgBitmap = new Compressor.Builder(context)
            .setMaxWidth(640)
            .setMaxHeight(480)
            .setCompressFormat(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG)
            .build()
            .compressToBitmap(imgFile);


    return compressedImgBitmap;
}
```

Comment: create folder programmatically before set dot(.)

Comment: @Pratik18 thanks but if you share code for creating .nomedia file or how can i Create a folder in 'Android' folder(where data & obb folders are present) then it will be ignored by gallery

Answer (score 8):

Create .nomedia file in Storage for hide audio from media player:

```
String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/";

File file = new File(filepath+".nomedia");
try {
file.createNewFile();
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Worked for me, no more photos displayed in gallery after capturing with camera.

Answer (score 0):

```
File files = getExternalFilesDir("");
File root = new File(files.getAbsolutePath()+"/Saveimags");
  if (!root.exists()) {
     root.mkdirs();
  }
File gpxfile = new File(root, ".nomedia");
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile);
writer.flush();
writer.close();


       File path = new File(root, "dump.png");
            try {
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(path);
                Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath);
                myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
                out.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Android/data/your package name/files/  this is your Android data folder path after you can save image in this folder.

Comment: should i pass image Uri which i get from activityResult method in 
 Like : getExternalFilesDir(Uri);

Comment: here : File path = new File(root, "dump.png"); instead of dump.png i am supposed to use my image Uri which i am getting from startActivityResult method . right? @ Patrik18

Comment: dump.png is image name. you can change your as your requirement.

Comment: you have to already convert bitmap use this bitmap in my code.

Comment: okay but what about the Uri which i am getting from startActivityResult in my onActivityResult() , have look at my code @ Pratik18

Comment: String path = getPathFromURI(selectedImageUri); you already get string path this set  Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("set your path");

Comment: So i have to place your code after i set bitmap in my imageView ? 

here imageCustomer.setImageBitmap(bmp); ?

Comment: yes.. both work done 1 is image set in image view and 2 image save in sdcard/internal